Solana wallet address
I'm currently working on a project with a partner, and I need some assistance.
Could someone guide me on how to automatically assign a Solana wallet address to users immediately after they sign up on my platform? This wallet address should then be usable for deposits.
Who can help with this?

You are possibly doing it incorrectly. Before the users go to your platform, your users should already have their own personal wallet (like Phantom). You can ask them to sign a message and verify its authenticity to authenticate them to your platform.

But some platforms automatically give you a wallet address immediately you Sign up on their platform to Thank you

IMO it defeats the purpose of self-custody. If you really want that, you can simply generate a keypair (Keypair.generate()), store the secret key on your database, perhaps encrypted using the user's credentials. Again, this is not ideal - and it defeats the ethos of web3. There are also providers such as web3 auth (https://web3auth.io/) and TipLink's Google login.

you can look into this package Web3Auth
it provides a better way to integrate and interact with the Solana Blockchain

You might want to try using an embedded wallet auth provider like dynamic or Portal. Rumours suggest that phantom will have one soon also.
With them, you can use traditional auth providers like Sign up With Google and have a wallet dynamically created for each user.
dynamic docs on this: https://docs.dynamic.xyz/wallets/embedded-wallets/create-wallets/overview#before-signup-pre-generated
